# regex function in chef inspec output

Tags: postgresql, chef-infra, inspec

I am using chef inspec for the postgressql.
I am executing the below command to match the output "local0". Because the output can be local0 or local1 etc. so given % to match any number value. but getting error. pls advise.

```
  describe command("sudo -u postgres psql postgres -c \"show syslog_facility;\"") do
    its("stdout") { should match ('local%') }
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to write a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that matches your criteria.

the following might do the trick

```rb
describe command("sudo -u postgres psql postgres -c \"show syslog_facility;\"") do
  its("stdout") { should match /local(\d)*$/ }
end
```